# Haskell Setter/over with multiple targets?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Is there a way to combine lenses, such that I can apply a function over a and b in the below structure, but not c?

```
import Control.Lens hiding (element)

data SomeInts = SomeInts {_a :: Int , _b :: Int, _c :: Int  } deriving (Show)
makeLenses ''SomeInts
```

Comment: Let me know (@) if the linked question doesn't satisfy you.

Comment: @dfeuer Could a `Traversal` be used for this? It seems they just want to use `over`.

Comment: @4castle, well, they could write a `Traversal`, sure, but they can't combine two lenses in an entirel generic way to get a valid `Traversal`.

Comment: The trouble will be the composition law, which generally objects to visiting the same element twice.